# Error inserting UID : 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'roor'@'localhost'

Tags: localhost, pn532

After installing mariadb and doing all the configuration process in need.
I've got this problem:mysql: unknown variable 'bind-address= 127.0.0.1'
i've ysed this site:https://devopscube.com/install-mariadb-on-ubuntu/ but it doesn't work.

I've tried to send data from my RPI 4B to my localhost but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do:

Check the Config File: Open up the MariaDB config file (usually something like my.cnf or my.ini). Look for the bind-address line. Make sure it's got the right IP address, which in this case is bind-address = 127.0.0.1.

Watch Your Spaces: Make sure there are no extra spaces or weird syntax issues in that line. It should read like this: bind-address = 127.0.0.1.

Give it a Restart: After you've tweaked the config, bounce the MariaDB service. Just run sudo systemctl restart mariadb in your terminal.

Typos Happen: Check and double-check for typos or little mistakes in the config. Sometimes those sneaky buggers can cause these headaches.

Comment: i've already did this and the error persist.